# Cell fracture not creating proper shards

Tags: add-on

So there is this model I try to use cell fracture on but the shards that are created are a bit off and I'm stuck on how to solve this problem. I looked for solutions for quite some time but nothing did the trick.

[image]

[image]

I tried "Limited dissolve" but no luck, I tried the "Remesher" modifier as well, it was a bit better but still not perfect.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Cell Fracture often can't break the object as expected if object is non-manifold (has some [wrong geometry of known types](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry/7914)). Look for it around areas which aren't cut properly

Comment: Alright I see, thanks for your comment, I'll have a look at it! :)